# adjoining root of an irreducible polynomial.

Tags: galois-theory

It's been a while since I last touched Galois theory. I want to check if this theorem is true:

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\varphi$ be a root of $f$.

Then $f$ is completed reduced over $\mathbb{Q}(\varphi)$. Is this correct?

A better way of writing this is probably if $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n$ are roots of $f$.

Is it the case $\mathbb{Q}(\varphi_1) = \mathbb{Q}(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x)=x^3-2$ which has roots $\{\sqrt[3]{2},\omega\sqrt[3]{2},\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}\}$
 where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity. If we adjoin $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ we get a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which fails to contain the complex roots.